# How do I upgrade my PHP 4.0 login script to PHP 5.6?

Tags: php, mysql, authentication, php-5.6, php4

my script below worked perfect on PHP 4.0 but my ISP upgraded to PHP 5.6 and now there seems to be something wrong (it does not connect to mySQL, etc), any help is appreciated

Many thanks

```
<?php
$userdb="var1";
$pass="var2";
$database="var3";

mysql_connect("sql.servername.com",$userdb,$pass);
@mysql_select_db($database) or die ( header('location: status4.htm') );
$match = "select id from USER_ACCOUNTS where username = '$username' and password = '$password'";
$qry = mysql_query($match)
or die ( header('location: status.htm?status=9') );
$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($qry); 

// Valid Username and Password
if ($num_rows > 0) { 
$qry = "SELECT * FROM USER_ACCOUNTS WHERE username like '%" . $username . "%'";
$res = mysql_query($qry);
$output='';
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)){
// loop through all returned results
$output .= '&viewUsername=' . $row['viewUsername'] . '&viewPassword=' . $row['viewPassword'] . '&username=' . $row['username'] . '&password=' . $row['password'] . '&name=' . $row['name'] . '&title=' . $row['title'] . '&email=' . $row['email'] . '&admin=' . $row['admin'] . '&file=' . $row['file'] . '&file2=' . $row['file2'] . '&file3=' . $row['file3'] . '&file4=' . $row['file4'];
echo "&status=1";
echo $output;
}
}
?>
```

Here is the mySQL 4.0 Table

```
id  viewUsername    viewPassword    username    password    name    title   email   admin   file    file2   file3   file4


1                                   user1       pass123     USER1   Manager email1   1      file1   file2   file3   file4
```

Comment: `mysql.*` extensions are deprecated, use `mysqli` instead

Comment: mysql extension might be deprecated but not removed prior to php 7

Comment: but yes it would be better if you used mysqli extensions

Comment: When you ask a question about an error, **ALWAYS** post the error log. To enable error reporting to your php code, append `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', '1');` at the top of your script, what does it return ?

Comment: This whole thing is just bad news all around. You really should hire someone to come in and go through your code with a fine toothed comb.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answers - here are the error messages...

Comment: Deprecated: mysql_connect(): The mysql extension is deprecated and will be removed in the future: use mysqli or PDO instead in /services/webpages/n/e/XXXXXXXXXXXXX.com/public/PHPLogin.php on line 11

Notice: Undefined variable: username in /services/webpages/n/e/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.com/public/PHPLogin.php on line 17

Notice: Undefined variable: password in /services/webpages/n/e/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.com/public/PHPLogin.php on line 17

Comment: Hi @Pedro Lobito  I updated the mysql extensions to mysqli and it still is not connecting (see below)

Comment: mysqli_connect("XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.com",$userdb,$pass);


@mysqli_select_db($database) or die ( header('location: status4.htm') );


$match = "select id from USER_ACCOUNTS where username = '$username' and password = '$password'";

$qry = mysqli_query($match)

Comment: `Undefined variable: password` -  seems to be the problem, make sure you get that value from the `POST/GET` request

Comment: Always add question-related information into the question itself.  This way future readers don't have to comb through the comments to understand the full story.  Please edit your question then remove your comments with the error messages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go example with PDO prepared statements

```
<?php

error_reporting(1);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');

// mysql connection
$db_host = 'localhost';
$db_user = 'root';
$db_pass = '';
$db_name = 'mydatabase';

$dbh = new PDO('mysql:host='.$db_host.';dbname='.$db_name.';charset=utf8', $db_user, $db_pass);

// submit form
if (isset($_POST['submit']))
{

    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];

    $stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM USER_ACCOUNTS WHERE username = :username AND password = :password");
    $stmt->bindParam(':username', $username);
    $stmt->bindParam(':password', $password);
    $stmt->execute();
    $number_of_rows = $stmt->fetchColumn();

    // Valid Username and Password
    if ($number_of_rows > 0)
    {
        $row = $stmt->fetchAll(); 

        $output = '';

        while($row)
        {
            // loop through all returned results
            $output .= '&viewUsername=' . $row['viewUsername'] . '&viewPassword=' . $row['viewPassword'] . '&username=' . $row['username'] . '&password=' . $row['password'] . '&name=' . $row['name'] . '&title=' . $row['title'] . '&email=' . $row['email'] . '&admin=' . $row['admin'] . '&file=' . $row['file'] . '&file2=' . $row['file2'] . '&file3=' . $row['file3'] . '&file4=' . $row['file4'];
            echo "&status=1";
            echo $output;
        }
    }

}

?>
```

And html form

```
<form action="" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username"><br />
    <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password"><br />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Login">
</form>
```

**Update**

```
<?php

error_reporting(1);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');

// mysql connection
$db_host = 'localhost';
$db_user = 'root';
$db_pass = '';
$db_name = 'mydatabase';

$mysqli = new mysqli($db_host, $db_user, $db_pass, $db_name);

/* check connection */
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
    echo "Connect failed: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    exit();
}

// submit form
if (isset($_POST['submit']))
{

    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];

    /* create a prepared statement */
    if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM USER_ACCOUNTS WHERE username = ? AND password = ?"))
    {
        /* bind parameters for markers */
        $stmt->bind_param("s", $username);
        $stmt->bind_param("s", $password);

        /* execute query */
        $stmt->execute();

        $number_of_rows = $stmt->rowCount();

        // Valid Username and Password
        if ($number_of_rows > 0)
        {
            $row = $stmt->fetchAll(); 

            $output = '';

            while($row)
            {
                // loop through all returned results
                $output .= '&viewUsername=' . $row['viewUsername'] . '&viewPassword=' . $row['viewPassword'] . '&username=' . $row['username'] . '&password=' . $row['password'] . '&name=' . $row['name'] . '&title=' . $row['title'] . '&email=' . $row['email'] . '&admin=' . $row['admin'] . '&file=' . $row['file'] . '&file2=' . $row['file2'] . '&file3=' . $row['file3'] . '&file4=' . $row['file4'];
                echo "&status=1";
                echo $output;
            }
        }

        /* close statement */
        $stmt->close();
    }
}
$mysqli->close();
?>
```

And try this

```
<?php

error_reporting(1);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');


$conn = mysqli_connect('host', 'username', 'password', 'table name');

/* check connection */
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
    echo "Connect failed: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    exit();
}

// submit form
if (isset($_POST['submit']))
{

    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];

    $query = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM USER_ACCOUNTS WHERE username = '$username' AND password = '$password'");

    if ($query)
    {
        // Valid Username and Password
        if (mysqli_row_count($query) > 0)
        {
            $row = mysqli_fetch_array($query);

            $output = '';

            while($row)
            {
                // loop through all returned results
                $output .= '&viewUsername=' . $row['viewUsername'] . '&viewPassword=' . $row['viewPassword'] . '&username=' . $row['username'] . '&password=' . $row['password'] . '&name=' . $row['name'] . '&title=' . $row['title'] . '&email=' . $row['email'] . '&admin=' . $row['admin'] . '&file=' . $row['file'] . '&file2=' . $row['file2'] . '&file3=' . $row['file3'] . '&file4=' . $row['file4'];
                echo "&status=1";
                echo $output;
            }
        }
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: Hi @Mario - I have copied the script exactly as you outlined and only updated the following (4) lines (with my variables) and it doesn't work (the original PHP 4.0 script worked for 5+ years until the ISP upgraded last week)

Comment: // mysql connection
$db_host = 'abc.server.com';
$db_user = 'user35400';
$db_pass = 'pass123';
$db_name = 'ADMIN_mydatabase_com';

Comment: @ServerProgrammer if you don't get any errors then script works fine. This is PDO connection it works on all versions of php. I tested it and works all fine.

Comment: I have used the above same (4) variables for the last 5+ years, not sure what I am missing?

Comment: I have ran the script exactly the way you have + updated the (4) variables, and I just tested to see if after the connection the script echos the value of "1" for status and it appears the script does not get this far (nothing is returned)

Comment: Can you double check the following to make sure I have this right - it is likely something small (like it usually is with PHP)

Comment: <?php
$userdb="var1";
$pass="var2";
$database="var3";

mysql_connect("sql.servername.com",$userdb,$pass);

Comment: <?php

//error_reporting(1);
//ini_set('display_errors', '1');

// mysql connection
$db_host = 'sql.servername.com';
$db_user = 'var1';
$db_pass = 'var2';
$db_name = 'var3';

$dbh = new PDO('mysql:host='.$db_host.';dbname='.$db_name.';charset=utf8', $db_user, $db_pass);

Comment: Sorry, I must have missed something - I just updated both scripts to indicate the variables I am using - thanks

Comment: Quick update - I have tried a number of suggestions but I can't get this to work.  I am an app developer (I am not strong on the PHP side) and I did write the original PHP 4.0 script (it took me a few weeks) and it worked perfectly for many years, but I may be over my head.

Comment: @ServerProgrammer can you post yours database table

Comment: I was thinking the same, maybe it has something to do with mySQL.  I just checked and I am running an earlier version, mySQL 4.0.  Perhaps this has something to do with it as well (I will post the database table as well)

Comment: @ServerProgrammer i updated my answer with 2 approach try them both.

Comment: Thanks - trying now :)

Comment: both your scripts are connecting without errors, I think I know where the problem rests - I am not using a standard html front end for the input of $username and $password, I am using a Flash front end.  As a result, the way I wrote the initial 4.0 script I would select the id from the USER_ACCOUNTS that matched the $username + $password ($match = "select id from USER_ACCOUNTS where username = '$username' and password = '$password'";)...

Comment: ...and if there was a match and the $rows where greater than '0' I would then pull the data from this match (I never used POST for the variables) - I think this is where all (3) scripts are failing (if ($num_rows > 0)

Comment: Yes problem was because of that. But i don't know how to you using that inside flash, i never was worked with flash.

Answer (score 0):

I would guess that on your old version you had `register_globals` enabled, thus in `$username` and `$password` you were getting directly what was posted from a form, which is no longer happening.

The quick solution would be to add at the start of the php code:

`$username = $_REQUEST['username'];
$password = $_REQUEST['password'];`

That being said, every line in your code screams bad practices and possible vulnerabilities. I would highly recommend you getting some help for a complete makeover if you are using that in a productive website.

Comment: Thanks Nazareno - I am using a html front end (input boxes) to add the username and password, I simply ran the debug script (without logging in) to see what errors it would throw